# jQuery mouse out and not hiding a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I've got two elements: an anchor which causes an occurence of a particular div.
In that single case I'm not able to wrap these two into a parent container, thus the whole markup has to be as following:

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">click me</a>
<div class="info">info displayed on trigger hover</a>
```

The very basic question is: **when the mouse leaves the trigger I want to hide the info window but only if the cursor is not over it.** 
How can I do that?

Help appreciated,
regards

Comment: When you say you can't wrap them, do you mean server-side, or client-side? is wrapping them via jquery an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't change the markup at all, you can give it a nice fade effect, and take advantage of the fact a fade isn't instant, something like this would handle every `.trigger`/`.info` pair:

```
$(".trigger, .info").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().andSelf().filter(".info").stop().animate({opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
    $(this).next().andSelf().filter(".info").stop().animate({opacity: 0 });
});​​​​​​
```

[You can try a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cXY22/), you could break this info one function for `.trigger` and one for `.info`, I was just keeping it a bit more terse.  The two function version would look [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cXY22/1/):

```
$(".trigger, .info").hover(function() {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
    $(this).next().stop().animate({opacity: 0 });
});
$(".info").hover(function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1 });
}, function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0 });
});
```

What this does is on `mouseenter` it fades in, on `mouseleave` it fades out (via [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/))...but moving the mouse from one to the other will let the fade happen for 1 frame before putting a [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to the fade-out and fade it back in.  To the user, they don't see that anything happened, when the mouse leaves both, the fade is allowed to continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.trigger').live('mouseout',function (event) {
    if (!$(event.relatedTarget).is('.info'))
        $(this).next().hide();
});
```

Comment: That is brilliant except the fact the trigger is a Google Maps API marker object and thus I'm not being able to interact with it the jQuery way (e.g. attach an event) - I don't even know whether it's possible to convert the marker somehow or use GEevent model?